# pageYOffset Not Working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I have a full screen landing page, and I want to know when that screen is full scrolled out, so I can bring in and fix the `navbar`. I am managing to get the hight of the device/window, but I can't get `pageYOffset` to fire of.

Here is my code:

```
export default class NavbarComp extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
    windowHight:"",
    navbarfix: ""
  };
  this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)
  }

getWindowHight(){
 let deviceWindow = document.getElementById('landing-section');
 let deviceWindowHight = window.getComputedStyle(deviceWindow).getPropertyValue('height');

console.log("from getinitiatlhight" + deviceWindowHight);

this.setState({
  windowHight: deviceWindowHight
  });
}

componentDidMount(){
 window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
 this.getWindowHight();
}

handleScroll() {
 console.log("scrolll" + this.state.windowHight);
 if (window.pageYOffset >= this.state.windowHight) {
  console.log("fix");
 } else if (window.scrollY < this.state.windowHight) {
  console.log("unfix" );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about React, but

```
this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)
```

doesn't seem right. handleScroll() isn't defined within the scope provided by `this` (hence why you're binding it after the fact. As such, shouldn't the code read:

```
this.handleScroll = handleScroll.bind(this)
```

Comment: Hi, this is ES6 syntax, so nothing wrong with it :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was

```
window.getComputedStyle(deviceWindow).getPropertyValue('height');
```

always return the value as a `string` like `2000px`. But, you need that to be a `integer` to do comparison. So, use the following to get the height in numbers

```
let deviceWindowHight = deviceWindow.clientHeight
```

The rest should work fine.

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pranesh456/0ycfru3n/15/
*Don't forget to open the console*